# Under which circumstances will the product of row norms equal the product of column norms?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Under which circumstances will the following hold?

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n ||A_i||_p == \prod_{j=1}^m ||A^T_j||_p
$$